# Minimal inradius of an arbitrary convex quadrilateral

Tags: geometry

How does one compute the minimal inradius of an arbitrary convex (not necessarily tangential) quadrilateral? Is there an easy formula I did overlook? Or is embedding the convex into a tangential quadrilateral the easiest approach?

Comment: There is no minimal inradius of an arbitrary convex quadrilateral, since the inradius can be as small as you like but not $0$. Perhaps you forgot to state some condition like the area or perimeter of the quadrilateral?

Comment: What do you mean by "minimal inradius of a convex quadrilateral"?

Comment: Perhaps you meant either the minimum circumradius or the maximal inradius?

Comment: Indeed minimal was a misnomer. I mean the radius of a circle fully enclosed by the quadrilateral, yet touching as many as possible edges. If there is more than one possibility touching three edges, choose the minimal.